# Is this possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, free-body-diagram, perpetual-motion

[image]
A picture that I found which boggles me .
Is this possible? Will the vehicle move? I understand the answer is no cause than the oil companies will go bankrupt.
But is there a physics explanation?
Can you explain it from the physics point of view? 
What if the man was not holding the stick but it was glued to the car.

Comment: It's a hard no from me

Comment: This is equivalent to trying to push a vehicle down the road from inside the vehicle.  Pushing your feet against the dashboard doesn't work.

Comment: Even admitting that one may have doubts.. but why then is this method not used? :-)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17177/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [**Newton's third law**](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/beginners-guide-to-aeronautics/newtons-laws-of-motion): If the magnet pulls the car forward, then the car must pull the magnet backward with exactly the same magnitude of force. But the magnet is anchored to the car via the pole and the driver, so pulling the magnet backward is equivalent to pulling the whole car backward. Add up two forces of equal magnitude and opposite direction, and you get _zero._ The net force on the car is zero.

Answer (score 2):

No. This would be like trying to move yourself to the right by pulling on your left arm with your right hand.